# Missing PR from GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to find the PR associated with a commit in `node-saml/node-saml`. I know there is an associated PR because I worked on it, and the description of the commit clearly says it was a merged pull request. I'm using this command:

```
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" --method GET /repos/node-saml/node-saml/commits/c1f275c289c01921e58f5c70ce0fdbc5287e5fbe/pulls -F per_page=100
```

What am I doing wrong?